# Count word over multiple columns

Tags: sql, select, count, distinct

I'm trying to count how often a word appears in different columns in a Select statement.
For example:

```
column1  column2  column3
No       No       No
Yes      Yes      No
Yes      No       Yes
Yes      Yes      Yes
```

So that if I would search after the word 'Yes' the result would be like:

```
count1  count2  count3
3       2       2
```

Could someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(case when column1 = 'Yes' then 1 end) as count1,
       count(case when column2 = 'Yes' then 1 end) as count2,
       count(case when column3 = 'Yes' then 1 end) as count3
from the_table
```

This works because the case will return a `NULL` value if the condition is not met. Aggregates ignore `NULL` values and therefore the `count()` will only count `yes` values.

Answer (score 0):

Count when a column contains the value with a combination of COUNT and CASE:

```
select 
  count(case when column1 = 'Yes' then 1 else null end) as count1,
  count(case when column2 = 'Yes' then 1 else null end) as count2,
  count(case when column3 = 'Yes' then 1 else null end) as count3
from mytable;
```